# Can I drop the helper of a draggable into a sortable instead of the original item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

For example, when I drag a draggable to a sortable, there is a helper that is different than the original draggable item. Can I drop that helper item into the sortable instead of the original draggable item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dropable plugin anywhere in combination with your draggable plugin to drag items from location A to B.
Then location B can be where you are using the sortable plugin.

=> You will drop items in the sortable

You can find here an example of the two plugins working together: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable

Comment: That's interesting... I ended up writing some hackery: When the beforeStop event fires for the sortable, I add an element exactly as desired into the sortable. By the time the stop event fires on the sortable, the draggable has been inserted into the sortable along with my new element i added during beforeStop, so during stop I just remove the draggable item. It happens so fast you never see the draggable item appear. It's a dirty hack though.... So I can put a sortable inside a droppable? That's interesting. I'll try that next time.

Comment: If you could describe what you'd or make an example that'd be nice.

Comment: Edited the original answer to add the example page http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable